# Final step of a random walk proof

Tags: binomial-coefficients, random-walk, stirling-numbers

I am working through the last bit of a [random walk proof](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2007/REUPapers/FINALFULL/Gupta.pdf) to show that a 3-d random walk is transient. The result I am looking for states that:

$\frac {1}{2}^{2s} {{2s}\choose{s}}  \sum_{j+k\leq{n}} (\frac {1}{3^s} \frac{(s)!}{k!j!(s-j-k)!})^2$ $= \frac {c}{n^{3/2}}$

I can understand that the above can be manipulated to get $\frac {1}{2}^{2s} {{2s}\choose{s}}  (\frac {1}{3^s} \frac{s!}{(n/3)!^3})$ and thence 
$\frac {1}{2}^{2s} {{2s}\choose{s}}  (\frac {1}{3^s} \frac{\sqrt{2n\pi}e^{-n}n^n}{(\sqrt{2s\pi} e^{(-s/3)}(\frac{s}{3})^{s/3})^3})$ by Stirling's approximation.

By distributing the powers and simplifying, I obtain $(1/2)^{2s} {{2s}\choose{s}} \frac{\sqrt{2\pi s}}{(\sqrt2\pi s/3)^3}$ which I can then get into the form $\frac{2\frac {1}{2}^{2s}}{2\sqrt{\pi/3}^3s^{2/3}}$ by applying Stirling again to the ${2s}\choose{s}$ term.

However, I would have though that the continued presence of n in the $1/2^{(2s)}$ would have meant that we can't refer to the numerator as a constant c?

Comment: What if you think of the 3-d random walk $(Z_1(t), Z_2(t), Z_3(t))$ as just a vector of independent 1-d random walks?  So $Pr[(Z_1(t),Z_2(t),Z_3(t))=(0,0,0)] = Pr[Z_1(t)=0]Pr[Z_2(t)=0]Pr[Z_3(t)=0]$.

Comment: It's fine to think of it like that, but I think my intention here is to prove that that's the case ;)

Comment: If you operate with continuous time Markov chains then it is directly the case.

Comment: So in continuous time $Pr[(Z_1(t), Z_2(t), Z_3(t))=(0,0,0)] = Pr[Z_1(t)]^3 = O(1/t^{3/2})$, which is summable over any equally spaced points in time $\{0, \delta, 2\delta, 3\delta, \ldots\}$.  The discrete time chain is just the embedded chain of transitions, which I think would follow the $O(1/t^{3/2})$ behavior.

Comment: This is a good insight Michael, although I'm not sure it answers the question  - certainly gives me something further to research.